# Pivot summary Oracle Apex

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

When I run report of oracle apex, pivot summary interactive report raised error, numeric or value error.

Comment: Did you applied a debug? if not please do it and share the results

Comment: Please provide a sample code or more information

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like your select statement is wrong. Perhaps add more information to your question?